# mysql syntax how to add a third table to $query

Tags: mysql, syntax, join

I have code:

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, c.name as categoryname, c.id as categoryid
          FROM #__table_one as a
          LEFT JOIN #__table_two c ON c.id = a.catid";

$query .= " WHERE a.published = 1
            AND a.access <= {$aid}
            AND a.trash = 0
            AND c.published = 
            AND c.access <= {$aid}
            AND c.trash = 0";
```

I would like to add a third table (**'__some_table'**) for the parts of the query where **a.publish, a.access and a.trash**. In other words, I want these fields to be retrieved from another table, not "**#__table_one**", but I do not know how to incorporate the **#__some_table** into the current query

I imagine the **JOIN** command can help me, but I do not know how to code mysql

Comment: I don't recognise the language you're programming your SQL into but your SQL makes me suspicious.  Go look up little Bobby Tables, then read up on how you use placeholders in queries.

Answer (score 0):

//not tested

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, c.name as categoryname, c.id as categoryid
          FROM #__table_one as a
          LEFT JOIN #__table_two c ON c.id = a.catid
          LEFT JOIN #__table_three d ON d.id = a.some_id";
```